# How to make a CSV file with arrays of varchar containing double quotes for PostgreSQL COPY

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I am preparing a CSV for loading onto a table using the SQL command:

```
COPY table FROM filename WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER)
```

This particular table has a `varchar[]` (array of strings) column, and some of the items in these arrays contain special characters such as double quotes (`"`) and backslashes (`\`), some of which can break the CSV format or the array notation. Examples:

```
"quote"
x1"x2
C:\Users
```

I've made a few attempts so far (attempt is the actual content of the column in the CSV file):

```
{"""quote""","x1""x2","C:\Users"}
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY table, line 1: "{"""quote""","x1""x2","C:\Users"}"

"{"""quote""","x1""x2","C:\Users"}"
Inserted value is missing characters:
{quote,x1x2,C:Users}

"{"\""quote\""","x1\""x2","C:\\Users"}"
Inserted value is missing characters:
{"quote\"",x1x2,"C:\\Users"}
```

What is the correct syntax to insert values with double quotes and backslashes from a CSV?

PostgreSQL version is 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The varchar[] column must be formatted using a CSV-formatted version of [PostgreSQL array notation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html). Unfortunately, as my example shows, this can get quite hairy.

Here are some examples how the column should be quoted:

```sql
copy (select
    'other-column'::text, 
    '{foo,bar,baz,Lucky''s Bar,"dbl\"quote",literal-backslash\\,brackets\[\]\{\}}'::varchar[],
    'another-column'::text
) to stdout with (format csv);
other-column,"{foo,bar,baz,Lucky's Bar,""dbl\""quote"",""literal-backslash\\"",""brackets[]{}""}",another-column
```

PostgreSQL has this [to say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) on quoting array elements:

> [W]hen writing an array value you can use double quotes around any individual array element. You *must* do so if the element value would otherwise confuse the array-value parser. For example, elements containing curly braces, commas (or the data type's delimiter character), double quotes, backslashes, or leading or trailing whitespace must be double-quoted. Empty strings and strings matching the word `NULL` must be quoted, too. To put a double quote or backslash in a quoted array element value, precede it with a backslash. Alternatively, you can avoid quotes and use backslash-escaping to protect all data characters that would otherwise be taken as array syntax.

As with all CSV documents, **if your column data contains quotes, spaces, commas, or other special characters, the column must be CSV-quoted**. Or just always quote them to be safe. Normal CSV output libraries will auto-quote columns in your data.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the array notation document talks about escaping double quotes and backslashes with a backslash, for which I wasn't too sure as there are no examples, so I may have missed it. It does get hairy: `"{""\""dblquotes\""""}"` (backslashed, then doubled for being an array element, then doubled again for CSV).